# Is there a way to use an ionic app as a web app?

Tags: cordova, web-applications, cross-platform, ionic-framework

I'm setting out to create a mobile app using Ionic.

However I would also like my app to work well and look good on a desktop.

Is there any way to create one app one time that looks good and works well on both platforms (and perhaps more platforms as well)?

Comment: You can use Ionic for web app if you want.

Comment: @HanhLe can you describe or link to how?

Comment: Do you try use it for web app? You can download Ionic example and run in browser. It working same as you develop app in mobile (exceed system api for mobile). I haven't example for web app.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you can use Ionic to build web apps. My suggestion would be to have a look at Ionic 2's components for they are implemented for mobile/tablet users, not desktop users. Ionic for web-apps almost feels like a coincidence; if you go back a few years, most looked at Ionic as a native app development and frameworks like jQuery Mobile for web apps.

When it comes to Ionic for web apps, they key term is Progressive Web App (PWA). Read more on this and you are good to go.

Check this out: http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-pwa-support-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is only intended to be used for mobile devices and is not tested on, developed for, or officially supported on desktop browsers.
-http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/why-no-desktop/7908/5

Having said that, the main logic of ionic apps are derived from [Angular](https://angularjs.org). By pairing angular with bootstrap or foundation (or your favorite responsive framework), you will get (I'm assuming) your ultimate goal of having a responsive site that looks well both on mobile and desktop, with all of the logical power of ionic.

If you decide to go this route, you can then use Cordova or Phonegap in order to compile your website into a mobile application that will act natively on mobile devices. Ionic actually uses Cordova under the hood so you will notice that syntactically they are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am tried to using ionic on my web app. Its working fine. But i have facing some issues likes browser scroll bar scrolling very slowly. You have to trying Ionic Material http://ionicmaterial.com/ or Angular Material https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/

Answer (score 0):

Some cordova plugin like sqlite-2,socialsharing,file-opner2 not supporting on browser.
If used this plugin you can't work on web app.
Cordova is not support for web app.